# Add header to existing pdf file in python

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to insert header `YasserKhalil` to `Sample.pdf` file.
Tried this code

```
import PyPDF2

def add_header_footer_pdf(input_file, output_file, header_text):
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

        for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
            page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]

            header = PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.createBlankPage(None, page.mediaBox.getWidth(), 30)
            header.mergeTranslatedPage(page, 0, 30)
            header.mergeTranslatedPage(PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.createTextObject(None, header_text), 0, 5)
            pdf_writer.addPage(header)

        with open(output_file, 'wb') as output:
            pdf_writer.write(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_header_footer_pdf('Sample.pdf', 'Output.pdf', 'YasserKhalil')
```

But I got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 20, in <module>
    add_header_footer_pdf('Sample.pdf', 'Output.pdf', 'YasserKhalil')
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 11, in add_header_footer_pdf
    header = PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.createBlankPage(None, page.mediaBox.getWidth(), 30)
             ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'PyPDF2' has no attribute 'pdf'
```

I tried to modify this line `header = PyPDF2.PageObject.createBlankPage(None, page.mediabox.width(), 30)`
but got another error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 20, in <module>
    add_header_footer_pdf('Sample.pdf', 'Output.pdf', 'YasserKhalil')
  File "C:\Users\Future\Desktop\demo.py", line 11, in add_header_footer_pdf
    header = PyPDF2.PageObject.createBlankPage(None, page.mediabox.width(), 30)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because the PdfFileReader class has been deprecated in PyPDF2 3.0.0 and you should use the PdfReader class instead. The code you have can be updated to use PdfReader as follows:

```
`import PyPDF2

def add_header_footer_pdf(input_file, output_file, header_text):
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as file:
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        for page_num in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)

            header = PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.createBlankPage(None, page.mediaBox.getWidth(), 30)
            header.mergeTranslatedPage(page, 0, 30)
            header.mergeTranslatedPage(PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.createTextObject(None, header_text), 0, 5)
            pdf_writer.addPage(header)

        with open(output_file, 'wb') as output:
            pdf_writer.write(output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    add_header_footer_pdf('Sample.pdf', 'Output.pdf', 'YasserKhalil')`
```

This code will now work without any errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already realized that and modified the code. But got a new error as illustrated in the main post.

Comment: The pdf attribute has been also removed from the PyPDF2 module in version 3.0.0. You can fix the code by removing the pdf attribute from the createBlankPage method call.

Comment: Updated the question after the suggestion of removing the `pdf` part.

Comment: I think you are getting this error because the width() method of the PageObject class takes a float as an argument, but the value of page.mediabox.width() is a decimal.Decimal object. You can fix the code by converting the value of page.mediabox.width() to a float using the float() function.

Comment: As you suggested I tried `header = PyPDF2.PageObject.createBlankPage(None, float(page.mediabox.width()), 30)` but got the error `TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object is not callable`

Comment: Hmm. Would you use the Decimal class's "to_float()" method to convert the "decimal.Decimal" object to a float?